# Creating a df of dates to pass onto a purrr function

Tags: r, purrr, lubridate

I am trying to create a `tbl_df` that has 2 columns `start_date` and `end_date`.  Every row would have 6 days between the `start_date` and `end_date`.  I want to use the `start_date` and `end_date` values from each row to feed into a  scrape function using `purrr::map`.

```
# example tbl_df
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~start_date,   ~end_date,
   "6/1/2019",  "6/7/2019",
   "6/8/2019", "6/14/2019"
  )

df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   start_date end_date 
#>   <chr>      <chr>    
#> 1 6/1/2019   6/7/2019 
#> 2 6/8/2019   6/14/2019
```

I tried to bind 2 vectors, but they are usually uneven length.  Is there a better way to solve this problem?  I'm also not sure if `purrr` would accept dates as an argument value.

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date


start_date <- lubridate::ymd("2019-06-01")
end_date <- lubridate::ymd("2019-08-01")

start_dates <- seq(start_date, end_date, by = "1 week" )
end_dates <- seq (lubridate::ymd("2019-06-07"), end_date, by = "1 week")
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Example function would be:

```
scrape_function <- function(start_date, end_date) {

url <- glue::glue("http://www.example.com/start_date={start_date}&end_date={end_date}")

# scrape data and return df

df
}
```

Also, how would I use the `start_date` and `end_date` values to pass along to `purrr::map2dfr` using `safely`?

Comment: In your scrape_function, you are passing the 'url' and returning 'df' (not clear)

Comment: The scrape function has a URL that takes a start date and end date.  Each call to the scrape function uses the URL and eventually get parsed into a df.  I didn't include the httr, and json steps in the example.  I want to row bind the multiple URL's that get built with the combination of start_date and end_date that feed into the scrape function.

Comment: Please check my updated solution with `map2`.  I can't test the scraping part as the url is dummy one

Comment: Assuming that the scrape function works properly, how would I wrap it in safely in case any of the scraping results don't return a df?

Comment: I would wrap the `scrape_function` with `possibly` i.e. `f1 <- possibly(scrape_function, otherwise = NA)` and then call `f1`.

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure I made my example clear enough.  I'm simply looking to create either a list, or df of dates to pass into the scrape function.  Row 1 would take a start_date input, and the corresponding end_date on that row would be 6 days later.  The new row would have 1 week between the start_date  and end_date on the first row and second row.  I guess it doesn't have to be in a df.  I just wasn't sure of the best way to sequence the dates in order to pass it into the purrr::map scrape function.

Comment: I cannot reproduce based on your example

Comment: Let's say I want to simply start with 2 inputs. start_date and end_date.  All I am looking to do is create a sequence of start_dates and end_dates to pass along to the referenced purrr::safely scrape.  What is the best way to create that sequence with just those 2 inputs?  Manually create a df, list, etc.?

Comment: Why the `map2(start_date, end_date, FUN = yourfunction)` wouldn't work

Comment: I need the sequence of start_date and end_dates to go beyond those 2 rows.  I was trying to create a sequence that went up to something like 2019-10-01

Comment: It would do that for 'n' number of rows with `map2` i.e. the `seq` from 'start_date' to 'end_date' of each row, by the '1 week' and returns a `list` of vector of dates

Comment: I am deleting my answer, as it is not clear from your example regarrding the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the web scraping code has just confused the issue. Is it just that you want to split a time period into 7 day chunks? Perhaps this

```
start_date <- lubridate::ymd("2019-06-01")
end_date <- lubridate::ymd("2019-08-01")

split_weeks <- function(start_date, end_date){
    df <- tibble::tribble(
        ~start_date,   ~end_date,
        start_date,  start_date + 6)
    interim_end_date <- start_date + 6
    while(interim_end_date < end_date){
        df <- df %>% tibble::add_row(start_date=interim_end_date + 1, 
                                     end_date=interim_end_date + 7)
        interim_end_date <- interim_end_date + 7
    }
    return(df)
}

split_weeks(start_date, end_date)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#>   start_date end_date  
#>   <date>     <date>    
#> 1 2019-06-01 2019-06-07
#> 2 2019-06-08 2019-06-14
#> 3 2019-06-15 2019-06-21
#> 4 2019-06-22 2019-06-28
#> 5 2019-06-29 2019-07-05
#> 6 2019-07-06 2019-07-12
#> 7 2019-07-13 2019-07-19
#> 8 2019-07-20 2019-07-26
#> 9 2019-07-27 2019-08-02
```

Or to fix your code to give vectors of equal length

```
start_dates <- seq(start_date, end_date, by = "1 week" )
end_dates <- seq(lubridate::ymd("2019-06-07"), by = "1 week",
    length.out=length(start_dates))
```

Comment: You hit the nail on the head.  I'm simply trying to create a sequence of two dates for passing into a scrape function argument.  Given the website limits, I want to limit the data to 1 week, but pass along a sequence of scrapes until the end date.  Your code appears to be perfect.  Only issue is the last value for end_date exceeds 8/1.  The second question I had was how would I pass along this df into a purrr function, or am I better off just creating 2 vectors of date sequences and passing to purrr::map2_dfr that way?